# Mean of an increasing function over exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I came across the following problem in my research

I have two random variables $X, Y$ which are exponentially distributed and $Y$ has a higher mean than $X$.

Then I have a function, say $f(z)$, which is known to be concave non negative and increasing in $z$.
Can I claim that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Y)] > \mathbb{E}[f(X)]?
$$

I tried with Jensen's inequality but it doesn't help to compare between two different random variables.
If not general it's sufficient for me to know if the claim holds fo $f(z) = \log(1+z)$.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know that $f(z) > 0$ or at least that $\int_\mathbb{R} f > 0$? Otherwise, likely there would be a counterexample...

Comment: the actual function is of the form f(z) = log (1 + z).

Comment: I tried with linear i.e., f(z) = mz where m is a constant and the claim holds. I don't understand the counter example gt6989b, could you please explain a little more

Comment: take $-x^2$, which is concave and negative and a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry for the omission but now I updated the question as f(z) being non negative and the actual function is like f(z) = log(1+z). thanks Seyhmus

Comment: however $-x^2$ is of course not increasing. so you need a general answer or only an answer for the $log(1+z)$ case.-

Comment: I only need for the log(1+z) case, but I have a feeling it will hole generally for the defined f(z), thanks

Comment: Are $X,Y$ independent? If so you can easily calculate the distribution of $(1+X)/(1+Y)$ and its density, then compute $E[\log((1+X)/(1+Y))]$ explicitly. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A useful idea here is called *coupling*. Let us start from the fact that every exponential random variable $Z$ with mean $z$ is distributed like $zU$, where $U$ is a standard exponential random variable. Since expectations depend only on distributions, one is asked to prove that, for every $x\leqslant y$, $E[f(xU)]\leqslant E[f(yU)]$.

Since $xU\leqslant yU$ almost surely, this holds true for every nondecreasing function $f$ (such that the two expectations are finite).

Comment: Concavity and nonnegativity are not needed.

Comment: Thank you Did. Could you please explain to me what you mean by " fact that every exponential random variable Z with mean z is distributed like zU, where U is a standard exponential random variable."?

Comment: I understood it Did, thanks a lot again. I have a result that depends on this claim. I would like to acknowledge you in my paper, if you wish.

Comment: Hello Did. Would coupling work even if $X, Y$ are defined in the same probability space? Thank you

Comment: ?? To get a coupling one **must** define X and Y on a common probability space.

Comment: Sorry the question should have been would coupling work even if $X, Y$ were in same probability space initially (before coupling)?

Comment: No, coupling provides random variables X' and Y' (possibly defined on another probability space Omega') such that X' is distributed like X, Y' is distributed like Y, and (X',Y') has nice almost sure properties. But the original (X,Y) can be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I also want to share my opinion although a very good answer is already available by @did. The $n$th moment of an exponential random variable is

$$E[X^n]=\frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$$

That is for every $n$, since $Y$ has a smaller $\lambda$ compared to $X$, we have a greater moment under $Y$ than under $X$. Since any linear scaling will not change the result, one can create an arbitrary function by the superposition of the scaled versions of $X^n$ for some set $n\in{\cal{N}}$. From the Taylor series expansion we can verify the claim.