# Distribution of the minimum of two random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Here is my problem. Let us consider X, Y and Z to be random variables following the exponential distribution (same mean or not does not matter).
I am trying to find the distribution of the $\min(\dfrac{X}{Z},\dfrac{Y}{Z})$. Can I compute the distributions of $\dfrac{X}{Z}$ and \dfrac{Y}{Z} then find the minimum ? or shall I proceed differently as I have the same denominator ?

Thanks.

PS : The distribution of the raio

Comment: Qais, do you know anything about the dependence between the variables?

Comment: R.v. are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume they are mutually independent. Since $X,Y,Z \geq 0$ we know $\min( \frac X Z, \frac Y Z ) = \frac 1 Z \min(X,Y)$. Then note that since $X,Y$ are exponential and independent, say $X \sim \exp(\lambda), Y\sim \exp(\mu)$, and $Z \sim \exp(\nu)$, then $M:=\min(X,Y) \sim \exp(\lambda + \mu)$, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Distribution_of_the_minimum_of_exponential_random_variables) for reference of this fact. Then you may check [CDF of a ratio of exponential variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables) for the CDF of the ratio of two independent exponentials,

$$
P[M/Z \leq t] = \frac{\lambda + \mu}{\nu/t + \lambda+\mu}
$$

for $t >0$.

Comment: Why computing $X/Z$ and $Y/Z$ then computing the minimum is incorrect ?

Comment: It would not be incorrect, but I don't see how to do it easily. You would get the CDF of $X/Z$ as $\lambda/(\nu/t + \lambda)$ and similarly for $Y/Z$. Then you would have to show that the CDF of the minimum of two RVs of that form has the CDF above. It's probably possible, but it makes more sense to use well known and easily accessible facts, like the distribution of the minimum of exponentials being another exponential.