# Having Trouble with Understanding the Minimum of Exponential Random Variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I'm learning about exponential distributions, and we've been given this distribution $Z = \min\left[X, Y\right]$, where $X$ and $Y$ follow exponential distributions.

How can I visualize this?

If $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(2)$, and $Y \sim\operatorname{Exp}(3)$, then $f_X(x) = 2e^{-2x}$ and $f_Y(x) = 3e^{-3x}$.

Would that just mean that $f_Z(x) = \min\left[2e^{-2x}, 3e^{-3x}\right]$, i.e. a piecewise function containing both distributions?

And how is $Z$ another exponential distribution if it is piecewise? I believe I am misunderstanding the meaning of minimum.

Comment: You are. In general, given two random variables $X,Y$ with pdf's $f,g$, the pdf of $\Phi(X,Y)$ is not $\Phi(f(x),g(y))$. To convince yourself of that, take simple examples of functions $\Phi$ and r.v.'s $X,Y$.

Comment: Ok, I guess I can't just assume that. What would the minimum represent then?

Comment: See e.g. this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471586/distribution-of-the-minimum-of-two-random-variables?rq=1 The general idea is that $\min(X,Y) > z$ if and only if both $X> z$ **and** $Y> z$, so that $$\Pr[\min(X,Y) > z] = \Pr[X> z \text{ and } Y> z]  =  \Pr[X> z]\cdot  \Pr[Y> z]$$ (the last equality by independence). This will give you the expression of the cumulative distribution function of $\min(X,Y)$, which by definition is $F(z) = \Pr[\min(X,Y) \leq z] = 1-\Pr[\min(X,Y) > z]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the minimum function will give the smallest of an observation of $X$ and $Y$ but not the p.d.f. itself since a value of a random variable does not take the value of the p.d.f. but rather take the "probability" from the p.d.f.

In general the trick is that if $Z>z$ and $Z=\min\left[X,Y\right]$, then it implies that $X>z$ and $Y>z$. Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you will have

$$P(Z>z)=P(X>z)\cdot P(Y>z)$$

When you work everything out, you will have $Z\sim\operatorname{Exp}(\lambda_x+\lambda_y)$.

Comment: Gotcha. I just had a misunderstanding of the relationship between a random variable and its PDF. Thanks for clearing that up!