# Probability density function of $X/Y$ for independent exponential random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$  be independent exponential random variables with parameters $λ_1$ and $λ_2$ respectively. What is the probability density of $X_1/X_2$?

I tried to integral form $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ but its seems I cannot work out a results.
If it need some other method?

Comment: Sometimes "exponential with parameter $\alpha$" means $\displaystyle e^{-x/\alpha}\,\left( \frac{dx}\alpha \right)$ for $x\ge0,$ so that $\alpha$ is the expected value, and sometimes it means $\displaystyle e^{-\alpha x} (\alpha \, dx),$, for $x\ge0,$ so that $\alpha$ is the rate and $1/\alpha$ is the expected value. Which of those do you have in mind? $\qquad$

Comment: "I tried to integral form $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ but its seems I cannot work out a results" Excellent! Please show the details of your computations.

Comment: Note that $Y = X_1/X_2 \le y$ is a sector of the first quadrant bounded by the $x_2$-axis and a diagonal line. Integrating the joint density over that sector gives you the value of the cumulative distribution function at $y.\qquad$

Comment: Also note that $\Pr(X_1/X_2 >0) = 1$, so you shouldn't expect negative numbers in the region over which you need to integrate. $\qquad$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables