# Distribution of $\frac{X_2-X_1}{X_2+X_1}$ when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d exponential variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

In  this  question, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are  independent  exponentially  distributed  random variables, each with parameter $\lambda$. I am asked to find the distribution of $\frac{X_2-X_1}{X_2+X_1}$.

I am not very comfortable with these types of questions just yet as you can probably tell. Can somebody explain this problem? I am getting 0 as a numerator but I am not confident in this answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Better to show whatever you have tried.

Comment: I have attempted the question again. I have that that the $X_1+X_2$ has a gamma (2,$\lambda$) density. Do I now just find the density of $X_1-X_2$ and divide to get the density for $\frac{X_1-X_2}{X_1-X_2}$?

Comment: Among other ways, one can try to find this using the transformation method involving jacobians. Haven't you done this before?

Comment: I have never heard my lecturer utter the word 'Jacobian' before in a lecture? My method is wrong?

Comment: You can find the densities of $X_1+X_2$ and $X_1-X_2$, but you cannot just divide the densities  to find the required distribution.

Comment: What would be the right way to approach this?

Comment: Take a look at my edit to see if you could follow the CDF method.

Answer (score 0):

A routine approach goes like this:

Write down the joint density of $(X_1,X_2)$.

Transform $(X_1,X_2)\to (Y_1,Y_2)$ where $Y_1=\frac{X_2-X_1}{X_2+X_1}$ and $Y_2=X_2+X_1$.

Calculate the Jacobian of transformation and hence the joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2)$.

Integrate the joint density of  $(Y_1,Y_2)$ wrt $y_2$ to find the marginal density of $Y_1$.

---

Alternatively, you could find the distribution function of $Y_1=\frac{X_2-X_1}{X_2+X_1}$, namely $P(Y_1\leqslant t)$.

For $|t|<1$, that last probability simplifies to

\begin{align}
P\left(\frac{X_2}{X_1}<\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)&=\iint_{\frac{y}{x}<\frac{1+t}{1-t}}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
\\&=\int_0^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\left(\int_0^{\frac{1+t}{1-t}x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\mathrm{d}x
\\&=\frac{t+1}{2}
\end{align}

This is the distribution function of a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$ for $|t|<1$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables?.